# Couldn't send message error from the Java ServerSocket

Tags: java, soap, serversocket

I am working on a legacy SOAP API client application.
In the unit test cases, it's implemented to start a mock server using ServerSocket class and return a SOAP string response.
Initially, that response string starts like below.

```
 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
        "<soapenv:Body>" +
```

But the test case was failing with a generic reason

> "COULDN'T SEND MESSAGE"

I debugged more and found the reason for the above error is a

> "CONNECTION RESET"

Since there are several reasons for the above errors I couldn't find the specific reason for the considering scenario.

But after checking the revisions of the code, I found that in the initial commits, the response SOAP string was starting as below.

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8\r\n" +
        "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
```

So, the only difference is below generic lines.

```
            "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8\r\n" +
        "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
```

So, I added the above lines again and tried. It worked !!!. The mock server could successfully return the expected SOAP response.

What I need to understand is the reason for the above behavior.